# How to determine the shape and sketch curve by hand for products of polynomials and exponentials

Tags: curves

How to:

- Determine the shape of,
- and sketch the curve *(Only x/y axis intercept points are required for labeling)*

for equations in the format of:

$$f(x) = a_1x^{b_1}\boldsymbol{e}^{c_1 x} +\ ...\ + a_nx^{b_n}\boldsymbol{e}^{c_n x}$$

where $a_i \neq 0$, $b_i, c_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Some examples of such equation:

$$ y = 20\ \boldsymbol{e}^{-{x\over2}} -20\ \boldsymbol{e}^{2x\over 5}+2 x\ \boldsymbol{e}^{-{x\over2}}$$

$$ y = \boldsymbol{e}^{-3x} + 3x\ \boldsymbol{e}^{-3x} + 25x^2\ \boldsymbol{e}^{-3x}$$

Comment: the 1st example you give is "out-of-shape" vs, the question you pose (why $e^{2x/5}$ ?)

Comment: @GCab The coefficient $c_i$ of $x$ in $e^{c_ix}$ may vary in each term.